# Ajax Call to Controller with multiple parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("AccountUpdate", "Customer")',
    async: false,
    data: { a:"ed", formCollection: $("#form1").serialize() }
});
```

**Controller:-**

```
public void AccountUpdate(string a, FormCollection formCollection) {}
```

**Question:-** In controller AccountUpdate I am getting parameter a ="ed" which is fine. 
But in FormCollection object I am getting the **formCollection object** and also the **'a'** object
Why the form collection object receiving the 'a' object ? It should be only formCollection object

Comment: Because your parameter is typeof `FormCollection` which is the collection of all submitted data. Replace it with `YourModel formCollection` Where `YourModel` is the model you used in the view.

Comment: So I changed my Controller's parameter to
**public void AccountUpdate(string a, Customer formCollection) {}**

No change in Ajax, Now I am getting null in formCollection ?

Comment: Also what I read is formCollection contains only those elements which are in the scope of form , "a" is not defined in form scope

Comment: Because your ajax `data` option is not correct. Just start by using `data: $("#form1").serialize(),` to ensure your model is binding correctly and I'll then show you how to send back the additional parameter

Comment: I did that before when I use only **data: $("#form1").serialize()** it works perfectly

Comment: In response to your comment about it _not being in the form_, the default ajax `contentType` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` which is why its added to `FormCollection`

Comment: Nice explanation Stephen Muecke, I learned something new Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of your POST method is typeof `FormCollection` which is a class that holds all submitted key/value pairs.

Change your method to

```
[HttpPost]
public void AccountUpdate(string a, Customer model)
```

And change your script to allow both your model and the additional value to be submitted and bound in the method

```
var data = $("#form1").serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'a': 'ed'});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("AccountUpdate", "Customer")',
    data: data
});
```

Comment: Thankyou  LeftyX and Stephen Muecke. 
Stephen Muecke your code is  working perfectly now,

Answer (score 1):

```
data: $("#form1").serialize()
```

is the way to go.

If you want to add some extra parameters:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("AccountUpdate", "Customer")',
    // async: false,
    data: "a=ed&" + $("form1").serialize()
});
```

This way you can bind directly to your view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string a, Customer customer)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lefty, but customer object is null now
This is my element in form

<input type="text"    name="ContactNumber"    />